# Flutter How do i set Stack Widget child in top,center and bottom

Tags: flutter

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frUo1.png)

[screen shot what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucmZK.png)

How do i set stack child of three,
1.AspectRatio
2.CircularProgressIndicator - center
3.Slider - bottomcenter

I have tried with alignments top center and bottomcenter its not changing,
Help me to fix this , and i have attached screen shot and code.
Its like youtube videoplayer slider in bottom and play/pause in center

```
Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: SliderTheme(
                    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                      activeTrackColor: Colors.red,
                      inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
                      trackHeight: 2.5,
                      thumbColor: Colors.red,
                      thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 5.0),
                      overlayColor: Colors.purple.withAlpha(32),
                      overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 5.0),
                    ),
                    child: Slider(
                      value: 5,
                      max: 10,
                      min: 0,
                      onChanged: (v) {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

Comment: if you want 3 widgets to be aligned one after another use `Column`, not `Stack`

Comment: but i need to overlay the child . please check ny screen shot that i attached. there you can find the circularprogressindicator and slider is in center , but i want to make circularprogressindicator as center and slider as bottomcenter @pskink

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Positioned` widget inside the `Stack` widget to obtain your desired outcome. An example is below:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      top/bottom/left/right  // use as desired
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Read more on the `Positioned` widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)

Comment: @mihansen3 nope using  **Positioned** cant able to set what i want its not accurate by give top with some value and bottom, please refer my second screen shot and give some brief example